# Wp Debug Enabled True Notices and Warning

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, warnings

Notice: Undefined index: Zumpito_event_full_day in /home2/michael/public_html/domainname.com/wp-content/themes/themename/included/main.php on line 246

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/michael/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/themes/themename/included/main.php:246) in/home2/michael/public_html/domainname.com/wp-admin/post.php on line 197

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/michael/public_html/domainname.com/wp-content/themes/themename/included/main.php:246) in/home2/michael/public_html/domainname.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228

The Code on Line#246 is this -

```
$arr['Zumpito_event_full_day'] = ( $_POST['Zumpito_event_full_day'] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['Zumpito_event_full_day]) : '';
```

---

Actually to an extent I found the solution here - 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/errors-notice-undefined-index-and-cannot-modify-header?replies=5

But i am a beginner so could not implement it in my case. Can some one specifically guide me how should I use Isset function in my case Here.

Comment: I forget to mention that when I set debug to False - define('WP_DEBUG', false);  These notices/warning disappears, but i have to eliminate theme in Debug Mode Enable or set to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr['Zumpito_event_full_day'] = isset( $_POST['Zumpito_event_full_day'] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['Zumpito_event_full_day]) : '';
```

this should solve your first notice

explanation is this in the link given by you

Comment: Thanks It was simple as soon as I implemented this the 2nd Notice also disappeared. Thank you so much from last 2-3 Hours I was moving from blogs to different forums, but was unable to implement isset correctly in my case. you made my day. Thank you so Much.